# My app used to build properly but now it crashes when i try to build

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios5

When I build it this is what the console says.

> 2012-07-18 14:23:41.351 Ink Wall[915:f803] *** Terminating app due to
>   uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Could not
>   find a storyboard named 'MainStoryboard_iPhone' in bundle NSBundle
>    (loaded)'
>   *** First throw call stack: (0x13cc022 0x155dcd6 0x4409f2 0x15d60 0x15ff8 0x1517f 0x24183 0x24c38 0x18634 0x12b6ef5 0x13a0195 0x1304ff2
>   0x13038da 0x1302d84 0x1302c9b 0x14c65 0x16626 0x222d 0x2195) terminate
>   called throwing an exception(lldb)

When I run the code it brings me to this code in the main.m file

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
@autoreleasepool {
    return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
}
}
```

It stops here and highlights the "return UIApplicationsMain... line saying:

> thread 1: signal Sigabrt

Comment: Usually, the app crashing and Xcode pointing at main() can mean anything. Mainly because an object added to the autorelease pool is over-released somewhere else (wrongly) and hence deallocated prematurely, but the error doesn't surface until the pool is drained (at the end of the @autoreleasepool block) when the object, already deallocated, is sent an extra 'release' message, triggering either a bad access exception or an 'unrecognized message sent to instance' exception, depending how far the deallocation has gone at that moment.

Comment: i would agree with you but the app crashes when i swap from one view controller to the other (which i didn't program- i used storyboard for this) but i have tried to program it to transition through code and it does the same exact thing. I dont understand why the code apple produces through its templates aren't working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well plain and simple.. according the that error, your storyboard "MainStoryboard_iPhone" no longer exists in the project.

Make sure that the actual name of your storyboard is an exact match to this:

[image]

Comment: where is that dropdown menu? you have to excuse me, lol this is my second day on 4.3

Comment: @nfoggia I added a new screenshot to my answer.

Comment: actually it still crashed, but that did need to be altered

Comment: @nfoggia Well, I'm sorry to say I'm not sure what the problem is. Good luck though!

Comment: Did you check that the resource is actually included in the target? (Right inspector in Xcode should show a checkbox near the middle, for each target name, when the resource file is selected in the project navigator)

Comment: If not, it will be absent at runtime (not bundled with the binary)

Comment: how do i check this? sounds like it could be the problem actually